# How I can enter multiple values in textbox variable in grafan and use it for repeate

Tags: grafana

I have a use case where I want to enter multiple order nubers in text box in grafan, comma selerated, and have multiple queries get diffrent info for thsoe orders. I want to user repeate option of Row so if I enter
order1, order2,order3 in text filed I get 3 row each with info I pull using queries across multiple DB.
[image]

I tried custom formatting no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with Tex box variables: their content is treated as a single value. But for repetition to work, variable should have multiple different values.

You need a variable of type *Query* or *Custom* with enabled Multi-select option.

---

If you cannot predefine list of orders for selection on dashboard creation (thus use of *Custom* is not possible), and total list of all orders is to large to be useful (thus making *Query* less than ideal), you might (depending on data source in use) employ a workaround: keep your current variable as is, but also add one more variable of type *Query* with multi-select option enabled. Use query, that will create this second variable only with orders listed in your original variable.

Then your user will be required to input list of orders (as it's done now), and after that tick "Selected" in second variable **twice** to select all.

This second variable can be used for repetition as expected by Grafana.

Comment: Workaround work, matter of fact it actually is better :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
with rws as (
  select '${workorder}' str from dual
)
  select regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).